# TYPO3 template override

Tags: php, html, templates, typo3

All,

I am working on a simple and straightforward site with TYPO3 CMS. Using a template, all of the pages have the same banner image displayed at the top of the page. I want to change this image on one of the pages to a different image. What is the best way to go about this?

The image is being loaded from a template extension called 'Banner' which looks like this:

```
temp.banner = COBJ_ARRAY
temp.banner {
# Menu 1 cObject
20 = IMAGE
20.file.import = upload/pics
20.file = fileadmin/template/main/template_1_FILES/{$banner_img}
}
```

I then tried to make a template extension on the one page which looked like this:

```
temp.banner {
20.file = fileadmin/template/main/template_1_FILES/otherimage.jpg
]
```

But this did not change the image. The original image was still displayed without any errors or sign that the extension did anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your changed the `temp.banner.` after it has been copied to another place. The TS from an extension template comes after all the TS from the original template has been parsed.

You must change either the constent via the `content editor` (see top select) or you have to change the exact place where the `temp.banner.` is copied to. You can use the `TS object browser` (see top select again) to find and change that place directly.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a constant `{$banner_img}` so just change that value in the template on the page where it should be changed.

I guess, if you rename your Object from `temp.banner` to `lib.banner` it will work like you expect. The reason is, that the name "temp" is really temporary. It will be removed from cached TypoScript Templates. So just avoid that name, if you do not really understand what happens.

What i mean:

```
temp.test = Hello World
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value < temp.test
```

That would output "Hello World" like expected. But `temp.test` is not available in other templates.